# Alter web page to append button and run VB.NET code on click

Tags: html, vb.net, append, webbrowser-control

I'd like to search for particular phrases within a WebBrowser dialog, and append a button after each, then on clicking that button, run a piece of VB.NET code.

E.G if it was searching for an `</a>` in this section of a web document

```
<p>Welcome to our <a href="#">website</a></p>
```

It would change that to

```
<p>Welcome to our <a href="#">website</a><input type="button" onlick="RUN_VB.NET_CODE_HERE"></p>
```

And that edited version of the webpage would be displayed to the user in the WebBrowser dialog.

Also, when you click the button that was appended, a piece of VB.NET code should execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the HTML simply change the document:

```
Dim str As String = WebBrowser1.DocumentText

str = str.Replace(something, buttonCodeText)
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = str
WebBrowser1.Refresh()
```

And the simplest way I can imagine for the button to execute something in Vb.NET is to do an action which you monitor with your program to detect when to start the action. For example adding specific text to the webpage, changing some value with javascript you can read, or visiting some webpage just to detect it and start your VB.NET code.

Comment: Should be enough to get it sorted out.
Thanks